# scala By-name parameter on a anonymous function

Tags: scala

I'm struggling to write an  anonymous function with by-name parameter. Here is what i tired.

```
val fun = (x: Boolean, y: =>Int) => if(x) y else 0
```

This fail with following error.

```
Error:(106, 31) identifier expected but '=>' found.
    val fun = (x: Boolean, y: =>Int) => if(x) y else 0
                              ^
Error:(109, 3) ')' expected but '}' found.
  }
  ^
```

How ever same code as a standard function works.

```
  def fun1(x: Boolean, y: =>Int) = if(x) y else 0
```

Any pointers ?

---------------Edit-----------------

I had a two part problem. senia answer solved the initial case. Suppose I have a function takes a function.

```
  def xxx[A,B](f:(A,=>B)=>B)={}
```

As per senia solution it works.

```
val fun: (Int, =>Boolean) => Boolean = (x, y) => y
xxx[Int,Boolean](fun)
```

However I wanna get rid of the intermediate fun and call xxx with anonymous function. Doing

```
xxx((Int, =>Boolean) => Boolean = (x, y) => y)
```

Will not work. Any ideas how to do this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could specify type of anonymous function, instead of types of parameters like this:

```
val fun: (Boolean, => Int) => Int = (x, y) => if(x) y else 0

scala> fun(false, {println("!"); 2})
res1: Int = 0

scala> fun(true, {println("!"); 2})
!
res2: Int = 2
```

`=> Int` is not a correct type name, it's a special syntax for by-name parameters in parameters block of method declaration or anonymous function type.

See [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) **4.6 Function Declarations and Definitions**

```
ParamType ::= Type
            | ‘=>’ Type
            | Type ‘*’
```

In case you don't want to assign anonymous function to variable you could either use type inference like this:

```
xxx[Int, Boolean]{ (x, y) => y }
```

Or specify its type this way:

```
xxx({ (x, y) => y }: ((Int, => Boolean) => Boolean))
```

Comment: Hi, Your solution works. However I have a one more thing. edited the original post. Can you help me.

Comment: Thanks really appropriate the help.