# Lazy arguments in lambda

Tags: scala, lambda, types, anonymous-function

Is it possible to inline the `my` function in the following snippet?

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec


object Ex14AppendViaFold extends App {
  val l = List[Int](1, 2, 3, 4)
  val l2 = List[Int](9, 8, 7, 6)

  def append[A](l1: => List[A], l2: => List[A]) = {
    def my(acc: => List[A], e: => A) = Cons(e, acc): List[A]

    List.foldLeft(List.reverse(l1), l2)(my)
  }

  println(append(l, l2))
}

sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]


object List{
  def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] = // Variadic function syntax
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

  def reverse[A](l :List[A]) =
    List.foldLeft[A, List[A]](l,Nil)((acc, elem) => Cons(elem,acc))

  @tailrec
  def foldLeft[A,B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: ( => B, => A) => B): B = l match {
      case Cons(h, tail) => foldLeft(tail, f(z, h))(f)
      case Nil => z
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876368/scala-by-name-parameter-on-a-anonymous-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala By-name parameter on a anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876368/scala-by-name-parameter-on-a-anonymous-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876771/5249621) answer:

```
  List.foldLeft(List.reverse(l1), l2)(
    ((acc, e) => Cons(e, acc)): ((=> List[A], => A) => List[A])
  )
```

So you can specify the type of lambda.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: @Patrick
Thank you for guiding me, I slightly modified my answer.